# Decode data from MySQL

Tags: mysql, export-to-csv

I have a database A(using MySQL) inside that there is table T. I have exported the table T using

```
SELECT * FROM T INTO OUTFILE '/root/table.csv FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

Fields of table.csv file have data AVi2B8uZGDdZ9omPqEGS which is not readable. I want to know how to decode the data AVi2B8uZGDdZ9omPqEGS

Comment: Where does that data come from? Is it not in the table? That seems unlikely - CSV is a cleartext format and there shouldn't be any encoding going on.

Comment: MySQL Ransomware Edition? (BTW, your command is incorrectly quoted.)

Comment: The data comes from table T.It is present in table T

Comment: Then I suggest you forget about CSV at this point and get back to your table. How do you currently use the table data? How do you insert stuff and what do you do with it when you read it back?